# how to read ChannelMessages using ms graph win. service app (in Application permission) using current userPrincipalName

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-identity-platform

We have a daemon app that connects to teams using MS graph.  It's using "Application Permissions" mode and Admin consent is granted for most permissions.  We are able to add channels (private or 'standard'), add/remove members, etc... from this service based on company requirements.  All is well.

For the ChannelMessages, we'd like to be able to retrieve them based on userPrincipalName, from the same tenant that the app is registered in.  (I know there is an ChannelMessage.Read.All with Application Permission and it requires us to submit a form to MS, we are not currently pursuing that route...).

Do we have to create ConfidentialClientApplication object to communicate with MS graph?  If so, how do we create a ClaimsPrincipal or ClaimsIdentity, based only on userPrincipalName?  Or is there a different solution to this problem?

Your help is appreciated.

thanks,
Art

Comment: currently you cannot read the channel messages using UPN you need to get the team id and channel id. could you please check this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT - we do have a hold of teamId, channelId, membershipId, aadUserId (through UPN).  The question is having all the four above - how do we read the messages in a channel.  More importantly, without AAD user's consent!?  We can't present the consent screen.
Also, is it possible, at the runtime of the service, to do it 'Delegated mode' given that Admin consent is granted?

Comment: If you want to provide the consent screen you need to use the application permissions. When you add application permissions on app installation user will receive the consent screen to grand the permission provided for the application.